# How to find Transpose Matrix?

Tags: matrices, transpose

I know how to find the transpose matrix in case of ($2 \times 2$) dimension But I get confused when i try to find Transpose matrix incase of $(3 \times 3)$ dimension .Because i cant apply rule of ($2 \times 2$)to ($3 \times 3$).

Let $$A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1& 2 & 3\\ 7 & 9 & 8\\ 5& 6 & 7 \end{matrix}\right]$$

How to find the transpose matrix of A ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you think the transpose of a matrix is?

Comment: If $A=(a_{ij})$ then $A^T=(a_{ji})$

Comment: Perhaps you should look up the definition of transpose first.

Comment: Maybe this gif will help you: https://goo.gl/images/nsT8Lt

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In my book it is clearly written " When the rows and columns of a matrix are interchanged, then the new matrix is called Transpose Matrix"

Comment: @Mathematician42 without knowing why would i post something totally unfamiliar to me ?

Comment: @Schl....r Then the answer is$$\begin{pmatrix}1&7&5\\2&9&6\\3&8&7\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you did it for the 1st row and coloumn what if i choose other coloumn for interchanging?

Comment: @Schl....r Then you'll something that is **not** the transpose.

Answer (score 1):

To find the transpose of a matrix - we have that the rows of the matrix become columns.

So here, we have $$A^T=\left[\begin{matrix} 1& 7 & 5\\ 2 & 9 & 6\\ 3& 8 & 7 \end{matrix}\right].$$